# RestSharp and multiple request parameter type

Tags: json, rest, api, restsharp

I've got api that uses key for authorization, second parameter is method. The problem appears when i execute request with another parameter with `RequestBody` parameter type. RestSharp documentation says that I cant use default `GetOrPost` parameter type with `RequestBody` parameter type because parameter with `RequestBody` will be overwritten by `GetOrPost`.

I tried to authorize by other methods like UrlSegment or `Authenticators` but api only accept that key with `GetOrPost` parameter type.

When i send that third parameter with `GetOrPost` type it is not working.

Here is the code i use:

```
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            var key = "11ECR0D5T9BIAC5DLXXGZ";
            var client = new RestClient(url);

            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;         
            request.AddParameter("key", key);
            request.AddParameter("method", "getProducts");
            request.AddParameter("application/json","{id:1}");
```

Is there any way to authorize with other parameter type ? Or send id parameter as other parameter type ?

Comment: Sorry, must be a missclick

Answer (score 0):

I've solve it by my own, i missed that the parameters must be named as "parameters" so it will look like: `request.AddParameter("parameters",jsonParam);`